# How to get Security description using Rblpapi?

Tags: r, bloomberg, rblpapi

I just want to get the security description output. Here is the code below just to get the security values.

In my bloomberg terminal it gives the description of "Generic First Corn" so I expect this as a result.

```
library(Rblpapi)
blpConnect()
bdh <- bdh("c 1 comdty", c('px_last', 'px_open'), start.date=Sys.Date()-31)
print(bdh)
```

Comment: You are querying the last price and the open price. You need to use another field if you want the description...

Comment: I figured it out I just needed to use bdp instead of bdh and pass "NAME"